# tslearnを用いた時のResumed because of empty clusterについて

Tags: python, python3, 機械学習

tslearnによるKShapeという分類手法を用いた時に、「Resumed because of empty cluster」と表記されます。

この場合、使っているデータセットの問題なのでしょうか、それとも学習回数など改善することによってうまく分類できるようになるのでしょうか。

アドバイスをいただきたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

```py
from tslearn.clustering import KShape
from tslearn.preprocessing import TimeSeriesScalerMeanVariance
seed = 0
np.random.seed(seed)
sz = train_data.shape[1]
train_data.shape #(400, 1, 300)
ks = KShape(n_clusters=2, n_init=30, verbose=True, random_state=seed)
y_pred = ks.fit_predict(train_data)
#ここで、Resumed because of empty clusterと言われてしまいます。
```

Comment: 回答される方へ http://teratail.com/questions/211379

Answer (score 0):

その表示が出ても待っていれば結果出力がされたりしますよ。
要因か分かりませんが
data shapeが（データ数、時系列の長さ、１）という形で私は使っています。